# JavaScript Regex - spaces between characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I found [a thread in the c# forums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614255/how-to-insert-spaces-between-characters-using-regex?newreg=bbf6ebeaeb32407287df168110cb75ca) that's exactly what I need, but I need it in JavaScript. Basically I need regex that will put spaces between each character of a phrase.

For example,

```
TEST
```

would become

```
T E S T
```

Explanations would be helpful, and I'm new to this, so please be nice :)

I'm building my project in a program that only allows regex code, so it needs to be that.

Comment: This is me nicely asking you what you've tried so far and why you want to use a regex for this. You can get by without one by splitting the string into characters then joining them with a space. `str.split("").join(" ");`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it uses offensive language.

Comment: What would `T  E   S     T  A` become ?

Comment: What kind of "program" would you be building your project in that only allows regex code? Regexps themselves do not manipulate or mutate strings; they only match. You can use routines such as `String#replace` to mutate a string based on the results of matching a regexp. However, if you are able to use `replace`, then you are also able to use `split` and `join`.

Comment: @torazaburo I'm making a translator at http://lingojam.com, and i have literally never coded before. im about ready to drop the question and give up, because, to no one's surprise, the internet responds to ignorance with rude messages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
"TEST".replace(/(.)(?=.)/g, "$1 ")
// Outputs
// => T E S T
```

- `(.)` Matches a single character. Captures in group 1(`$1`)
- `(?=.)` Positive look ahead. Checks if the captured character is followed by another character.
- `"$1 "` Replacement string. `$1` Contains the character captured in group 1, followed by a space
- `g` Global modifier. Applies the replace globally for all the matches within the string.

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/fZ8tZ5/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
(.)(?!$)
```

And replace with `'$1 '`(space)

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xI9qQ3/1)

Answer (score 0):

You say you want this in JavaScript, then you edited your question (after I posted this answer) to say you must use a regex. Without that (strange, to me) requirement, you can do this with `split()` and `join()` in JavaScript without using a regex.

```
var myString = "TEST";
var result = myString.split('').join(' ');
console.log(result); // "T E S T"
```

For this and all the regular expression solutions so far provide, if you will have special characters, this will be problematic. For example `'foo  bar'.split('').join(' ');` returns an unexpected result. So does `'foo  bar'.replace(/(.)(?=.)/g, "$1 ");` and `'foo  bar'.replace(/(.)(?!$)/g, "$1 ");` as well. But if you know you are dealing with (say) ASCII-safe text, then there won't be any problems.

Comment: There are no "multi-byte" characters in JS strings. There are just Unicode characters. Split and join will work fine on any characters.

Comment: @torazaburo I was thinking of the problem described at https://github.com/mathiasbynens/esrever#why-not-just-use-stringsplitreversejoin. I think you're right, though, that this will not apply here.

Comment: Oops, I take it back. There absolutely are problems with this and unusual characters. For example, try this in your browser console: `'foo  bar'.split('').join(' ');`

Comment: What is that character?

Comment: It is this Unicode character: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1D306/index.htm

Comment: It's a character on a secondary plane, which is not going to work very well in any context.