# How to avoid google translate to translate :parameters

Tags: excel, regex, laravel, excel-formula, google-translate

I'm using a library [nikaia/translation-sheet](https://github.com/nikaia/translation-sheet) who basically pulls all the translations from the Laravel site into a google spreadsheet making it "easily" translatable with `=GOOGLETRANSLATE(A1)`

The problem comes with the parameters:

- :price
- :amount
- :etc

So I've got the idea to substitute ":" with @nonmakingsenseworblablaprice so Google couldn't translate example:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(GOOGLETRANSLATE(SUBSTITUTE(B2;":";"@nonmakingsenseworblabla");"ES";"EU");"@nonmakingsenseworblabla";":")
```

Well, not sure why Google eats some letters and puts new ones:

```
:amount de saldo -> @nonmakingseseworblatamount of saldo
```

So I decided to do something like detect the parameter and change :amount to :*a_m_o_u_n_t* and that is apparently working and not being weirdly parsed converted or translated.

I was looking for a solution and found a [similar idea](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T009634_Adding_Dashes_between_Letters.html) but having problems migrating it to spreadsheets script plus is not detecting the parameter

Any one knows how to detect all :parameters in a sentence and put a symbol, slash, dash etc between the characters or letters? Example:

```
The amount :amount for this order number :order_id is :price
```

I've also tried regex but not been lucky so far

```
=REGEXREPLACE(GOOGLETRANSLATE(REGEXREPLACE(B22; ":(\w)([\w]+)"; "{%$1_$2%}"); "ES";  $C$1); "{%(\w)_([^_]+)%}"; ":$1$2")
```

There's a regex to [select the spaces between letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614255/how-to-insert-spaces-between-characters-using-regex), but good luck making that in excel or spreadsheets. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wH1nK1/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've created a script to avoid parameters translation:

```
  function translate(cell, lang) {
  const content = cell.toString();
  const keys = [];
  const enc = content.replace(/:([\w_]+)/ig, function(m, param) {
    const n = `[§${keys.length}]`;
    keys.push(param);
    return n; 
  });
  return LanguageApp.translate(enc, "es", lang).replace(/\[§(\d+)\]/ig, function(m, param) {
    return `:${keys[param]}`; 
  });
```